# ArcGIS - Point Density with Geocode data - not working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, density

I would like to create a simple density map based on a geocoded data but the output shows up as blank.

Below are steps I took:

1. Add data - Import raw data based on Excel which has postal code (field: postal) and # of freq (field: visit_count).
2. Geocode data - the raw data is geo-coded and saved as a layer named ABC
3. I go to Spatial Analyst Tool -> Point Density
   selected ABC as input point features, population is selected as visit_count
   output cell size set as 50
   neighborhood - circle
   radius set as 1000
4. After I run the results show High: 3.40282e+038 to Low: -3.40282e+038 and nothing shows up on the map view. 
    When i looked at the results tab it shows a warning Skipping feature(s) because of NULL or EMPTY geometry.

Could anyone help me identify how to go about fixing this?

Edit: Below is the before & after point density.

[image: Before Point Density][image: After Point Density]

Comment: Are you sure the geocoding is done correctly? The error message leads me to believe that the features have no geometry, i.e. are not geocoded corectly?
-can you project the features?

try Data Management tools --> Features --> Check Geometry------

see also (https://geonet.esri.com/thread/159784)

Comment: hi there i have attached the before & after pictures - could you help me figure out what went wrong?